# Elastic search "InnerHits" Vs Doing an extra call

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Currently i am having product(child) and supplier(parent) types which have parent-child relationship.In scenario where i need to show the natched products with there respective suppliers i am using "innerhits" to fetch the supplier(parent) along with product(child), which is working fine.

But now i have gone through an article which says that "innerhits" slows up the query.so now i am having an alternate approach which is to make a single call to supplier(parent) type and fetch all the suppliers for the needed products.

BRIEFLY PUTTING : (InnerHits) Vs (making separate call), which of the two approaches is advisable.

Comment: The approach that is advisable is the one that works best with your cluster and data, i.e. the one that puts the less burden on your cluster. You've tried both approaches, how do they compare performance-wise?

Comment: I haven't tried the second approach(making separate call), i want to check whether using "inner-hits" to retrieve parent documents is a performance killer or not, if so then i am planning to eliminate  "inner-Hits" and make a separate call.